# Perl: read from <>

Tags: perl, readfile, diamond-operator

What does reading from `<>` do in Perl? For example, what will the following do?

```
print for(<>);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The so-called diamond operator (`<>`) reads line-by-line (in scalar context) from STDIN or the filename(s) specified as command-line arguments.

From [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators):

> The null filehandle `<>` is special: it can be used to emulate the
>   behavior of sed and awk. Input from `<>` comes either from standard
>   input, or from each file listed on the command line. Here's how it
>   works: the first time `<>` is evaluated, the `@ARGV` array is checked,
>   and if it is empty, `$ARGV[0]` is set to `"-"`, which when opened
>   gives you standard input. The `@ARGV` array is then processed as a
>   list of filenames.

---

In list context, `<>` returns all lines, with each line stored as an element in the list.

This means that `print for <>;` will do the same thing as `print while <>;`, albeit with more memory.

Answer (score 3):

You've found the single most magical piece of Perl. Well, I'm sure there's *more* magical things, but this little idiom makes it *very* easy to write programs intended for shell pipeline use *and* file-operation use.

When run without any arguments, `<>` will read lines one-at-a-time from standard input.

When run with arguments, it'll treat the arguments as filenames and read lines one-at-a-time from the named files in turn.

A short demo:

```
$ cat > print.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
print for(<>);
$ chmod 755 print.pl 
$ echo hello world | ./print.pl 
hello world
$ ./print.pl print.pl 
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
print for(<>);
$ ./print.pl print.pl print.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
print for(<>);
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
print for(<>);
$
```

I typed in the program by hand there; hit `^D` when you've typed it in completely.

Answer (score 0):

It reads from standard input, one line at a time, and stores it to `$_`. print then prints out `$_` by default since it is not given an argument. This program reads from standard input and echoes to standard output until it reaches EOF.

Comment: I did. Stack overflow ate the underscore for some reason.